# Is "Double is not a numeric type" a compiler bug?

Tags: idris

I'm seeing the compiler error

`Double is not a numeric type`

Since I haven't defined my own `Double` type, this seems blatantly not true given [this excerpt from Brady's book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/type-driven-development-with-idris/chapter-7/164). Am I correct in thinking this is a bug in the compiler, at least in that it's an inaccurate error message?

Comment: Can you post your code? Idris 1 or Idris 2?

Comment: @michaelmesser idris 1. I was hoping to avoid posting the code, as it's really complicated, which is why I'm not asking for a solution, only to rule out one possibility. Will post if the question's really not answerable